# System command in Android

Tags: android, command, system

To run system Command like "ping" in android device , we can use [Process](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html) to execute them. 
I have difficulty in accessing that data which is replied by system for systme commands.
how to set that data in proper format? how to access it and store in different type of variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at [Root Tools](http://code.google.com/p/roottools/) - they make it dead simple.

**Edit**: Ofcourse this works also for non-root commands on non-root devices ... look at `getShell(boolean wantRoot)`

Comment: i cant understand how to use this roottools.... i mean how to use in my android project....

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/roottools/wiki/Usage has a step-by-step usage guide, it is really easy. Look at the chapters "Including the Library in Eclipse" and then  "Running root commands". If you use ? getShell(false)` instead of `getShell(true)` you run a normal command, not as root.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you executed your command by getting the `DataOutputStream` for the process. The same way, you can get the command's output by getting the `DataInputStream` for the same process. However, this will show you all the output. You will have to implement separate logic to parse through this output, make some sense of it and further process it. I suggest you first get the `DataInputStream` and print out the output, so you get a better idea. There is no easy way to do this, except probably the answer from Eugen Rieck.

Comment: i used this command 
`Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -c 8 " + url);`


and i use output of this with StringBufferReader and i dont know how to parser it.